# Error after calling endTurnWithNextParticipant on a GKTurnBasedMatch in iOS using game center

Tags: ios

I corrected the leaderboard id in the new update of my iOS turn based game and now I'm getting this, has anyone seen this before?
This is right after submitting my turn data by calling endTurnWithNextParticipant.

It seems the server also can't match players against each other anymore but invites work fine.
Everything works fine in the simulator but not on the device.

Even with the error the data gets submitted and the other player sees it and can play the entire game to the end but this error gets logged with every turn:

Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not
be completed due to an error communicating with the server."
UserInfo=0xee64400 {NSUnderlyingError=0xee51590 "The operation
couldn‚Äôt be completed. status = 5001, Missing versions for adamId:
123456789 from bundleVersion: 1.4 adamId: 123456789 game: Tic Tac Toe
Unlimited Free compatGames:null", NSLocalizedDescription=The requested
operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with
the server.}

Any ideas?
Thanks